# I cannot open any other programs while hard disk is reading/writing

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, read-write

The laptop becomes very slow that opening chrome while moving files get the laptop unresponsive.

Windows explorer uses all disk resources.

**Laptop: ideapad 330-15ikb**

**CPU: i7 8550u**

**ram: 8gb**

**HDD: seagate 5400rpm**, the hdd is in a good health

I had another laptop which was i5 6th gen with the same hdd and i could run 1-3 programs while hdd is busy and there was not that lag

I know that I should expect that unresponsiveness but not in that way.

**Question 1**: Is there a problem in the laptop or hdd that i should worry about?

**Question 2**: Is there a temporary solution like limiting hdd read/write speed so there would be some left to open few programs beside it.

Comment: Normally the OS itself (its "I/O scheduler") should be doing this limiting...

Comment: Check for updates to your drivers, especially relating to disk and chipset. Also for BIOS update (from manufacturer only). Check if this is happening when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: Hard disks are bad in serving more than one request at a time (because of the weight of the head that is reading the data and it's movements). This is true especially for slow HDDs like yours (only 5400 rpm). Therefore this is the normal behavior. If you want more performance you need an SSD.

Comment: How do you know your HDD us in good health? Also, have you tried defragmenting it? This might help by reducing head movement somewhat, and also by using the faster outside if the platter first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SSD solved the issue.................

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).